# How to find the number of bytes rewritten to a folder hierarchy?

Tags: filesystems, performance, stat, statistics

I want metrics for how much writing and reading have been done to a folder.

`vmstat -d` gives metrics at the whole disk level. `iotop` will give per process rw stats.

But how can I find out how much writing has been done to a folder or file?

Comment: Can't you compare the outputs of two different `du -sx` invocations?

Comment: Related / possible duplicates: [How can I monitor disk I/O in a particular directory ?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9520), [How to monitor I/O stream in a particular Linux directory or file ?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/62121)

Comment: You may want to clarify what *"how much writing"* means for you. Difference between the directory sizes before and after writing? Amount of data sent to the underlying block device?

Comment: @don_crissti, one of those answers involved loopback mounting the directory in question - gotta love the simplicity of it.

Comment: @peterph, one movtivation is estimating SSD longevity due to caching proxy server rewrites.  Amount of data sent to an underlying block device due to /var/proxy/cache/, but not not /var/log/.

Answer (score 0):

Given the clarification in the comment - the need of knowing how much data is being sent to the underlying block device (e.g. for the purposes of logging activity on SSD) - you'd need to check this in the file system driver **and** below (which usually is part of the kernel). Note, that just writing to a file doesn't mean the data gets really sent or even written to the device - there usually is lots of caching between the `write()` system call in user space and the actual bits making it into the wires connecting the hard drive to the controller.